# Java Nio.FloatBuffer Serialization

Tags: java, serialization

I want to send FloatBuffer accros machines (using RMI mechanism), but with Java Nio.FloatBuffer i got notserializable exception.

How can  i send these buffers using Remote method invocation.

thanks

Comment: Why the buffer? Why don't you simply send the bytes in it? That's the whole idea behind it. Isn't it?

Comment: Thanks for reply, On the client side i want the FloatBuffers, therefore i am  looking to transfer those via RMI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buffers are not Serializable. You can extract the floats in the buffer (using FloatBuffer.get(float[]) and send them as a float array via RMI and rebuild the buffer out of the array at the other side (FloatBuffer.wrap(float[]).